# Search through a 2-dimensional list without numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I'm looking to define a function that accepts two parameters: an `int` and a `list`.

If the function finds the integer in the list it returns its *coordinates*.

For example how would I do that for the number 4 in the following list, **without using numpy**?

```
l = [
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
```

You can assume that the target will always show up only once and will always be contained in the list.

Comment: What if the target shows up more than once?  What behaviour should there be if it isn't in the list?

Comment: The target will always show up only once and will always be contained in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
l = [
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]

def findElement(element, l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            if element==l[i][j]:
                return (i,j)
    return None

print(findElement(4,l))
```

Output:

```
(11, 7)
```

Comment: Since I have only started to discover Python a couple of weeks ago, I find your code to be the prettiest because it is the least obscure of them all. Thank you!

Comment: Please don't use `range(len...` when you can use `enumerate`. There are very little situations where `range(len...` is the pythonic way, and this is not such a situation. If you don't believe me, maybe you believe [Ned](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o). :)

Comment: @timgeb thank you for your remark, I was mostly thinking of providing a readable solution for Mister Tusk rather than a pythonic one. Good point. Thank you for the link as well :)

Answer (score 6):

> The target will always show up only once and will always be contained in the list

You can use `enumerate` to enumerate the outer lists and the elements of the inner lists.

```
def coords(lst, find):
    return next((i, j) for i, sub in enumerate(lst)
                       for j, x in enumerate(sub)
                       if x == find)
```

Demo with your list `l`:

```
>>> coords(l, 2)
>>> (1, 1)
>>> coords(l, 1)
>>> (1, 2)
```

In case you later want to adapt the function to work properly if the target is not in the list, remember that [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) takes an optional `default` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would used solution like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
# ---------------------
l = [
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 4, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
# ----------------------------------
def search(value,listin):
    coords = [[ival,kkval] for ival,dd in enumerate(listin) for kkval,val in enumerate(dd) if val==value]
    return coords
# ----------------------------------
result = search(4,l)
print result
```

where I defined a function search, which can be used to search for certain value from an input list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

```
def matrix_search(target, matrix):
    for row_index, row in enumerate(matrix):
        try:
            return (row_index, row.index(target))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('Target {} not found'.format(target))
```

Sample usage:

```
print(matrix_search(4, l))
```

Notes

- To search a simple list, use the `.index()` method
- The `.index()` method will either return the index of the element if found or throw a `ValueError` if not found. In our context, we just ignore this exception and move on to the next row.
- At the end of the loop, we will throw an exception because the element is not found