# Matrix-"lookup" function for given parameters in Python

Tags: python, lookup

I want to build a function in python which is able to look for specific values inside a custom defined matrix.
Something like that:

```
PR1 = [["a","b","c","d"],["LTV1",2,3,4],["LTV2",6,7,8]]
PR2 = [["a","b","c","d"],["LTV1",10,11,12],["LTV2",14,15,16]]
PR3 = [["a","b","c","d"],["LTV1",18,19,20],["LTV2",22,23,24]]

def lookup(....)

lookup("PR1","a","LTV1")=2
lookup("PR2","c","LTV2")=15
```

How would you construct such a "lookup" function?

Thanks,

KS

Comment: You need to be a little clearer about the logic by which `lookup` should operate.

Comment: For example, we recently had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084961/search-through-a-2-dimensional-list-without-numpy/53085140) but it's unclear to me why your function takes three arguments.

Comment: what do u mean? I think the example above quite straight forward..
Anyways, I have three parameters in my custom lookup(...) function:

Comment: 1. parameter: determine the table; 2. parameter: determine the column of the table; 3. parameter: determine the row of the table

Comment: What about `lookup("PR1","d","LTV1")` ?

Comment: So if `["a","b","c","d"]` are the columns and `["LTV1", "LTV2"]` are the rows, why are there only three values in each row, not four?

Comment: As far as I know there is no lookup function in Pyhon, thats why I have to build it by my own...This is the whole point why I'm raising this question.

Comment: Should be four, I adjust it.

Comment: Also, `lookup("PR2","c","LTV2")` should return `16`, not `15` by my logic. Can you confirm it?

Comment: @KostaS. are the two answers you got going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library if you want to work with labeled rows and columns.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> PR2 = [["a","b","c","d"],["LTV1",10,11,12,13],["LTV2",14,15,16,17]]
>>> columns = PR2[0]
>>> rows = [sub[1:] for sub in PR2[1:]]
>>> index = [sub[0] for sub in PR2[1:]]
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns, index=index)
>>> df
>>> 
       a   b   c   d
LTV1  10  11  12  13
LTV2  14  15  16  17
>>> df['c']['LTV2']
>>> 16
```